# Pass Docker variable to React index.html file

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am already familiar on passing Docker environmental variables to a React app by prepending the variable in the `docker-compose.yml` file with **"REACT_APP_"** string.

However I would like to do something similar in the `index.html` entrypoint that loads the actual React application.

Context: Imagine you want to pass a Google API key for a Google API and you want to swap between development and production Docker containers through docker-compose rather than by editing index.html.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a blog post about a similar, related topic last month -- let me know if this helps: https://www.brandonbarnett.io/blog/2018/05/accessing-environment-variables-from-a-webpack-bundle-in-a-docker-container/

TL;DR: create a shell script that auto-generates a static JS config file in your web server container. Here's how:

config.js

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "window.appConfig = { API_URL: '${API_URL}'} " >> config.js
cat config.js
apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

Dockerfile

```
COPY --from=build-env /src/config.sh .
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./config.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/config.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
...
environment:
  - API_URL=http://localhost:8082
...
```

index.html

```
<!-- config.js has to come before your bundle -->
<script src="config.js"></script>  
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20130632)

Comment: Good call. Pulled in some content